# How to get a thumbnail of a window in C#?

Tags: c#, aero, dwm

How do you go about getting a thumbnail of a window, like Windows 7 superbar preview, or Aero flip? Note that I do not want a screenshot of the application, there is a way in DWM to get this information.

I would like a C# way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Already [been done by Bart de Smet](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/05/4495.aspx), he used the new Vista DWM api to achieve  that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [Mimic](http://mimic.codeplex.com/) - it's entire purpose is to do this, although it is a standalone app.