# How to get a screenshot of non visible or minimized window?

Tags: c#, thumbnails, screenshot, dwm

I want to get a screenshot of non visible or minimized window and save it as bmp. I know how to do it with visible window. It's easy. But get non visible is quite difficult. 
I have looked over Internet and didn't find any example. 
I know that Desktop Window Manager get window's thumbnails. [DWM example](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/05/4495.aspx) But I didn't find any example how to convert thumbnail to bmp.

P.S. Please don't suggest me to bring window in front, get a screenshot and then minimize it.

Comment: Maybe this question will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858122/saving-a-screenshot-of-a-window-using-c-wpf-and-dwm OR this http://spazzarama.com/2009/02/12/screen-capture-with-vista-dwm/ which specifically says the window doesn't need to be visible.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/24/432229.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I can't examine your advices now. As soon as I could do it I'll write about result obligatory.

Comment: @TheGreatCo You were close. It helped.[http://spazzarama.com/2009/02/07/screencapture-with-direct3d/](http://spazzarama.com/2009/02/07/screencapture-with-direct3d/) Thank you.